# Cordova project: Jquerymobile to Framework7 migration

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, migration, html-framework-7

I would like to convert my Cordova project from **jquery-mobile** to **Framework7**. 
Is there any tool or best practice that can be followed to minimize the time needed?

Answer (score 1):

After some months I did not find any tool to automate the conversion and probably is not even needed.

Bottom line is that the Framework7 documentation is the best resource for info.

One point to note is that Framework7 replace in a whole both jquery and jquerymobile.

Html tags are all to be reassigned and, for javascript, many structures are exactly the same between jquery and Framework7, while others require a specific rewriting.

I can confirm is not a particularly hard task to move from jquery to Framework7.